# onmousemove event results in wrong position

Tags: css, rust, dom-events, coordinate-systems, yew

I am trying to move an element in the screen using Yew. When element is in the top left of the screen, I can move it correctly. But when the element starts in other position, it gets to a wrong place when trying to move it. It seems that the unwanted behaviour depends on the distance from the top left of the screen from where the element is.

I tried to reproduce same logic in React achieving the expected results, but do not know why in Yew I have this strange behaviour. A sandbox is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-ives-jexwmu?file=/src/App.tsx).

This is the element I want to move.
`piece.rs`

```
use yew::prelude::*;

struct Coordinates {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

#[function_component]
pub fn Pawn() -> Html {
    let coordinates: UseStateHandle<Coordinates> = use_state(|| Coordinates { x: 0, y: 0 });
    let is_dragging: UseStateHandle<bool> = use_state(|| false);

    let onmousedown: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
        let is_dragging: UseStateHandle<bool> = is_dragging.clone();
        Callback::from(move |event: MouseEvent| -> () {
            event.prevent_default();
            is_dragging.set(true);
        })
    };
    let onmouseup: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
        let is_dragging: UseStateHandle<bool> = is_dragging.clone();
        Callback::from(move |event: MouseEvent| -> () {
            event.prevent_default();
            is_dragging.set(false);
        })
    };
    let onmousemove: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
        let coordinates: UseStateHandle<Coordinates> = coordinates.clone();

        Callback::from(move |event: MouseEvent| -> () {
            event.prevent_default();
            //web_sys::console::log_1(&is_dragging.to_string().into());
            if *is_dragging == true {
                coordinates.set(Coordinates {
                    x: event.client_x(), 
                    y: event.client_y()
                });
            }
        })
    };

    html! {
        <div
        class="pawn"
        onmouseleave={onmouseup.clone()}
        onmousedown={onmousedown}
        onmouseup={onmouseup}
        onmousemove={onmousemove}
        style={format!("left: {}px; top: {}px;",
         coordinates.x, coordinates.y)}>
         <img src="img/pawn.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
        </div>

    }
}
```

The following code is added for the question context and to make an reproducible example, these are the `main.rs` and `index.html` files:

```
use yew::prelude::*;
mod board;
mod piece;
use piece::Pawn;

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    let is_flipped: UseStateHandle<bool> = use_state(|| false);
    let onclick: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
        let is_flipped: UseStateHandle<bool> = is_flipped.clone();
        Callback::from(move |_| match *is_flipped {
            true => is_flipped.set(false),
            false => is_flipped.set(true),
        })
    };

    let set_pawn = |square: &String| -> Html {
        if square.ends_with("7") {
            html! {
               <Pawn />
            }
        } else {
            html! {}
        }
    };

    let render_squares = |squares: &Vec<String>| -> Html {
        html! {
            <tr>
                {
                    for squares.iter().map(|square|
                    html!{
                        <td class="square"><p class="nomenclature">{square} </p> {set_pawn(square)}</td>
                    })
                }
            </tr>
        }
    };

    html! {
        <div class={".container"}>
        <table>
            {
            for board::create_board(*is_flipped).iter().map(render_squares).rev()
            }
        </table>

        <aside>
        <button onclick={onclick}>{"Flip"}</button>
        </aside>
        </div>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Yew App</title>
    <link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="img" />
  </head>
  <style>
    html {
      color: white;
      user-select: none;
      background-color: black;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
    table {
      aspect-ratio: 1 /1;
      width: 100vw;
      max-width: 100vh;
    }
    .square {
      color: black;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: white;
      position: relative;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
    tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
      background: green;
    }
    .nomenclature {
      font-size: calc(0.25rem + 1.25vmin);
      position: absolute;
    }

    .pawn {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: grab;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
  </style>
</html>
```

Finally, this a method needed to create the layout to be shown.

`board.rs`

```
type Board = Vec<Vec<String>>;

pub fn create_board(flipped: bool) -> Board {
    let mut board: Board = Vec::new();
    let mut columns: Vec<char> = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
    let mut rows: Vec<char> = vec!['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

    if flipped {
        columns = columns.into_iter().rev().collect();
        rows = rows.into_iter().rev().collect();
    }
    for row in rows {
        board.push(Vec::new());
        for column in &columns {
            let mut square = String::new();
            square.push(*column);
            square.push(row);
            let len: usize = board.len();
            board[len - 1].push(square);
        }
    }

    board
}
```

How can I fix this and be able to move an element correctly in Yew?
Why this logic seems to work in React but not in Yew?

EDIT:
When I console log the event coordinates, these three are identical.

```
web_sys::console::log_1(&event.client_x().to_string().into());
web_sys::console::log_1(&event.screen_x().to_string().into());
web_sys::console::log_1(&event.page_x().to_string().into());
```

EDIT 2:
The problem seems to be in `position: relative;` in the `.square` style. If I apply this to the react example, it results in same unwanted behaviour as in Yew.

Comment: You probably have an issue with mixing up coordinate systems relative to different origins, but I'm not familiar with the details.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I will research about coordinate systems. Maybe I can fixed with a css property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in two steps:

First, I removed `position: relative` in `.square` css selector, which is the direct parent of `.pawn`. This was causing the strange behaviour when moving the element.

Second, because the initial state of `coordinates` was `{x:0, y:0}` in the `piece.rs` component,  all the elements where stacking in that position. To solve that I created a closure to prevent setting up that initial position:

```
 let set_position = || -> String {
        if coordinates.x != 0 && coordinates.y != 0 {
            format!("left: {}px; top: {}px;", coordinates.x, coordinates.y)
        } else {
            "".to_string()
        }
    };
```

And then passed it to returning html tag:

```
html! {
        <div
        class="pawn"
        style={set_position()}>
        onmouseleave={onmouseup.clone()}
        onmousedown={onmousedown}
        onmouseup={onmouseup}
        onmousemove={onmousemove}
         <img src="img/pawn.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
        </div>
```

I realized this when using devtools in the browser and finding that, after unselecting `top` and `left` properties in the element, it went to its expected initial position. Also, it was important to notice that in the react example, I did not use `position: relative` in the direct parent.

UPDATE:

Alternatively to that, you can use rust `Option` type to set first state as `None`:

```
struct Coordinates {
    x: Option<i32>,
    y: Option<i32>,
}
...

let coordinates: UseStateHandle<Coordinates> = use_state(|| Coordinates { x: None, y: None });

...
coordinates.set(Coordinates {x: Some(x),y: Some(y)});
```

And then finally conditionally use it in the div style:

```
style={if coordinates.x.is_some() && coordinates.y.is_some() {format!("left: {}px; top: {}px;", coordinates.x.unwrap(), coordinates.y.unwrap())} else {"".to_string()}}>
```

Or if you liked the previous closure approach:

```
let set_position = || -> Option<String> {
    match coordinates.x.is_some() && coordinates.y.is_some() {
        true => Some(format!(
            "left: {}px; top: {}px;",
            coordinates.x.unwrap(),
            coordinates.y.unwrap()
        )),
        false => None,
    }
};
```